# What causes the errors in the rules that come with Commerce Coupon?

Tags: commerce, rules

I am trying to use [Commerce Coupon](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_coupon) module in my project. The problem is after download and enable this module, rules created by this module got error. And I can't find out what happened to this errors.

- commerce coupon - 7.x-2.0-rc2+14-dev
- commerce version - 7.x-1.11+39-dev
- inline Conditions - 7.x-1.0-alpha7

[image]

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason for running into this error is because the entity metainfo for "commerce_coupon_number_of_uses" is not provided, unless you have created a 'coupon type'.

In that case, try to create such coupon type and verify if it removes those errors.